# sorl-thumbnail multi-page pdfs

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

It is possible to use sorl to thumbnail multi-page pdfs?  I know you need to use the ImageMagick back end to use pdfs at all.  But I am having no success with multi-page pdfs.  Looking at the source I think it is because the convert command when it sees multi-page pdfs such as foo.pdf creates a set named foo-1.jpg foo-2.jpg etc... and I don't think sorl expects to see this type of output from 1 file.  Is there a way to do this/workaround/patch?

Comment: Have you filed a bug report at https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail/issues?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve this myself and made an adjustment which modifies the call to convert.

See my patch here:

https://github.com/jamting/sorl-thumbnail/commit/6a4d705db3529640a9e193044b615f24ff96eef4

HTH!

Comment: This fix was merged a few months later: https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/pull/73