# how to display PDF thumbnails using sorl-thumbnail package

Tags: django, python-3.x, sorl-thumbnail

I am trying to develop a django app for displaying the thumbnail of first page or cover page of PDF,i don't need to save the thumbnail image in DB, can anybody help me with this,
I'm Using python 3.X and Django 1.9.6

Comment: Please tell us how far you achieved ?

Comment: when i tried i was able to get the thumbnail of image ,but not PDF that i wanted . here is my code in template : `{% thumbnail "http://www.aino.se/media/i/logo.png" "40x40" crop="80% top" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}`

Comment: @RajaSimon  while i  was googling, i found that this was a bug in sorl-thumbnail but later it was fixed  reference:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394048/sorl-thumbnail-multi-page-pdfs <br/> but i have no idea how to do it